# Terminal keep linking with IDE when open the IDE from terminal

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-terminal, ide

I'm using Webstorm as my IDE. Most of the time I open the IDE from the terminal. After opening the IDE it stays linked to the terminal (as shown in the image). If I close the terminal, the IDE also closes. Is there anyway to fix that. I need to separate these two.

**OS**: elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera x86_64

**Kernel**: 5.3.0-42-generic

**Terminal**: io.elementary.t
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening any application throw terminal the process will the linked to the terminal that opened it.
But you can disown the process that was opened in that terminal and then close it without affecting the application by using the following syntax:

```
webstorm & disown
```

Syntax using with webstorm as example and the general case would be

```
command & disown
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks ⚡️